# Convert NSString to NSDictionary and NSDictionary to NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdictionary, nsdata

There are many questions on this already, but the answers given are situation-specific, answering the poster's personal problem rather than the question title.

I would like to know if there is a general, universal, easy way to convert an `NSString` to an `NSDictionary`, and vice versa?

I've got difficult/complex/non-cross-platform approaches, but surely there must be an easier way?

Here's what I know / have tested:

1. Apple provides a `Dictionary` -> `String` method that has no inverse, and works perfectly so long as your Dictionary is only basic datatypes, arrays, and dictionaries. This covers most real-world cases, but Apple doesn't give an inverse :(.

   1. `[myDictionary description];`
   2. // no way back ? Why not?
2. Apple has an intermediate approach using `NSData` that fails silently, so that it only works in a LIMITED set of real-world cases:

   1. `[myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`
   2. `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` // NB: silently fails in many cases, returns nil string
3. Apple has MULTIPLE, INCOMPATIBLE ways of converting `NSDictionary` -> `NSData` -> `NSDicitonary` that work well - but they are using `NSData`, so they are not a straight conversion, and they are harder to work with

   1. KeyedArchiver:

      1. `[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myDictionary];`
      2. `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:myData];`
   2. PropertyListSerialization:

      1. `[NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plist format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];`
      2. `[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format errorDescription:&error];`
   3. NSJSONSerialization:

      1. `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:0 error:nil];`
      2. `[dataWithJSONObject:myDictionary options:0 error:nil];`

As it stands, the only route that is GUARANTEED to work appears to be:

Write lots of code to output a verbose `XML` or `JSON`, converting it to `NSData`, then converting *back* into `NSString`, and send that on the wire.

Anything else has a slightly-less-than-100% success rate. Unfortunately, this technique turns a very common problem (string -> dictionary -> string) into a multiline chunk of silly boilerplate code we shouldn't be writing.

Also ... the `XML`-or-`JSON` approach is the only one that correctly reports failures (if they occur) - both the encoding systems take `NSError` pointers.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you don't want to use JSON.  It is kind of stupid that Apple doesn't supply object <==> NSString versions of their conversion routines, but you can easily fix that with categories or you can use one of the half-dozen third party JSON packages for iOS.

Comment: Because this problem comes up frequently, on many projects, and it's annoying to waste time and money writing boilerplate code that's supposed to be in the core libraries. I would like to be a better programmer - to waste less of my employer's money - and know how to do this fast + accurate. I would log a bug against Apple's libs, but my experience of doing that so far is that they generally reject any requested additions to the core libs.

Comment: It's not that hard to write the category and include it in your projects.  Only a couple of small files.  (If you don't like working with Apple you can always switch over to Android.)

Comment: You're right. We have no need of standard libraries. Most of the features are only a couple of small files, and it's not hard to write them. While true ... that ignores a lot of points in their favour.

Comment: I gather you're being facetious.  Any (worthwhile) platform has it's "guardians" of the architecture, and they are often a bit rigid in their views of what's "right", to the point of absurdity in many cases.  But it's a very thin, gray line to walk, and not everyone can be as insightful as you and I in terms of knowing the *true* "right" way to do things.

Comment: No, I think the libraries are great. That has nothing to do with my desire to write better code, and to avoid lengthy pointless boilerplate when trying to achieve simple recurring tasks.

Answer (score 10):

> Apple provides a Dictionary -> String method that has no inverse

Huh? False. And no, you are not supposed to rely on `description`. Use property lists instead.

Forwards:

```
NSData *plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization
    dataWithPropertyList:theDict
                  format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                 options:kNilOptions
                   error:NULL];

NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:plist encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Backwards:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSPropertyListSerialization
    propertyListWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                 options:kNilOptions
                  format:NULL
                   error:NULL];
```

Sidenote:

> and works perfectly so long as your Dictionary is only basic datatypes

those are called "property list objects".

Comment: Thanks. If you read my question to the end, you'll see that I'm familiar with PropertyListSerialization - I've used it many times.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is:

```
id<nscoding> obj;

NSData * data     = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:obj];
NSString * string = [data base64EncodedString];
```

And then the other way around

```
NSString * string;

NSData * data    = [NSData dataFromBase64String:string];
id<nscoding> obj = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]
```

You can add base64EncodedString and dataFromBase64String: with the NSData category available here [NSData+Base64](https://github.com/l4u/NSData-Base64)

NSUTF8StringEncoding return nil when you try to encode something that is not data made of an utf8 string.

Comment: That's great, if only base64 were supported by Apple. I thought there was an NSFoundation class somewhere that included it, but I can't find it now - probably I've just used one of the github copies before.